# How to build `boost` with custom `iconv` on Linux?

Tags: c++, boost

I need some functionality from latest `iconv` in my program, so I built custom `iconv`. However, on Linux (at least Ubuntu) there are also built-in `iconv` implementation `libc`; it is impossible to remove it, because removing `libc-dev` will also remove `llvm` and many other critical packages.

So, I use `ICONV_PATH` to set path to my custom `iconv` when I build `boost`, so I have not to link 2 `iconv` versions to my program: system one for `boost` and custom one for my custom code:

```
./b2 install -j12 variant=release link=static threading=multi --prefix=/my/prefix -sICONV_PATH=/my/iconv/path
```

The problem is that `boost` build system completely ignores `INCONV_PATH` and still uses system `iconv` without any feedback whether it even tries to use custom `iconv` and why it is ignored.

Are there any way to build `boost` on Linux with custom `iconv` when `libc-dev` contains system `iconv`?